# YouTube API 2 Get All comments .net

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I am using youtube api 2.0 to get comments.
Currently i have this:

```
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(new YouTubeRequestSettings("Project", devKey));
Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId);
Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
var comments = request.GetComments(video);
```

How i can change `StartIndex` to get all videos?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to retrieve more than 100 comments per video. As YouTube won't allow it. However, by using start-index 1, you can get first 1-50 and with start-index 51, you can retrieve 51 to 100th comments